# Can you wear armor over an Aegis Astral Skin?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics, aegis

Can you wear armor over an Aegis Astral Skin?

> **Astral Skin:** When formed in this way, an astral suit resembles a psychoactive skin.
>
> **Psychoactive Skins:** A deployed skin completely covers the wearer and all his equipment like a second skin, allowing the wearer to see, hear, and breathe normally. It rolls away from various parts of the body as needed, such as when the wearer needs to eat or access a backpack. Held items or items specifically excluded are not covered by a psychoactive skin.

Now does the statement "completely covers the wearer and all his equipment like a second skin" prevent armor being worn over it. The Astral Skin give no armor bonus unless Custom Point are used for it, I get that. If you can wear Armor over the Astral Skin, will this hamper other suit options like, Augment Weapon, a second application Nimble, Flight, or Underwater Breathing and Swim Speed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the astral skin, like a psychoactive skin, can be worn under armor. That’s the whole point of it. It does not interfere with the armor in any way, though any armor bonus you get the astral skin to give you won’t stack with your armor, nor will some armor abilities if they are on both the skin and the armor.

It’s kind of unfortunate, though, because there is just no good reason to use anything *but* the astral skin as a result of this. With the astral skin, you get to combine the aegis abilities with an armor you buy, which is just great. But since you have real armor in the way, you can’t easily swap to a different type of astral suit for some other circumstance.

Comment: KRyan: Do you have an idea what Suit mods that you can custom the just the Astral Skin with an armor over it? or do you think there is a list out there? Cause I kinda want to see where recent build or PC is going. As always thanks for quick and courteous response.

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver Pretty much all of them? I can’t think of any that don’t work. The only problem would be if the armor and the skin had the same special armor property; then those might not stack.

Comment: That sounds...sound. The only thing I can think of besides the same properties not stacking, might be the Increase Size and Improve Increase Size as it mentions that suit and gear grow and treated a one size larger. The worn armor might get in the way of such expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, I believe the Astral Skin would be on the outside of any worn armor (just like the Astral Armor and Astral Juggernaut do), but would not interfere with the armor's function or abilities in any way, and neither would the armor interfere with the Astral Skin in any way (excepting that the armor bonuses and similar effects wouldn't stack). Referencing your rules quote:

> **Psychoactive Skins:** A deployed skin completely covers the wearer and all his equipment like a second skin, allowing the wearer to see, hear, and breathe normally. It rolls away from various parts of the body as needed, such as when the wearer needs to eat or access a backpack. Held items or items specifically excluded are not covered by a psychoactive skin.

The phrase "all his equipment" would include worn armor, especially taking into account the mention of a backpack, which would be worn over armor. There is, though, no real reason that it just fits to the wearer with armor, backpack, etc over it. Though the wording "when the wearer needs to eat or access a backpack" opens the question: can the skin prevent others from opening the Aegis's backpack?

To respond to one of your comments on @KRyan's answer, as well, worn armor will not interfere with Increased Size or Improved Increased Size:

> **Increased Size:** The astral suit grows in size and the aegis and all of his equipment is treated as one size category larger as if affected by expansion. The aegis must be at least 9th level to select this customization.affected by expansion."
>
> **Expansion:** This power causes instant growth, doubling your height, length, and width and multiplying your weight by 8. This increase changes your size category to the next larger one...
>
> All your equipment, worn or carried, is similarly expanded by this power.

Comment: Miler: If the Astral Skin or Psychoactive Skill fully encases the user armor, and equipment carried, doesn't that make the armor useless as it will not give you the AC bonus of the armor and only the AC the Astral Skin or Psychoactive Skin has. Aegis Astral Skin give now AC bonus unless you count the Dex bonus to AC due the free custom Nimble the Astral Skin gives or some Psycho active Skins give no AC bonus. Hence the Idea of wearing an suit of armor over an Astral Skin or Psychoactive one that is deployed. That's where I was concerned about size change. The armor is outside the skin.

Comment: In game terms, the Astral Skin being inside or outside the armor doesn't matter for the purposes of AC, as Astral Skin, by default, doesn't impact the AC provided by additional armor. Astral Armor and Astral Juggernaut are different, as they specifically state `the astral suit encloses the armor and the aegis gains the benefits of only his astral suit and not that from his armor`. Since Astral Skin does not have this line, it does not impact any armor you are wearing. I mention armor bonus with Astral Skin in my answer because you can add Improved Armor to it, which grants an armor bonus.